# Stuck trying to get an href attribute value below the div on a mouseenter

Tags: jquery

Need to grab the value of `data-name` when I hover over `<div class="hover_over">`

```
<div class="hover_over">

    <a href="somelink">some value</a>

    <div class="menu_info1">
    <div class="menu_info2"></div>


    <div class="user_menu popover">
        <div class="user_menu_nipple"></div>
        <div class="user_menu_list"></div>

      <a href="someotherlink" class="targetclass" data-name = "What_I_Need" >           
            </a>
     </div> ...
</div>
```

Using `this.href` to get "somelink" but stuck trying to seek further down.

Here's how I'm getting "somelink":

```
$(".hover_over").mouseenter(

function () {

localStorage['ls1'] = this.href;  
localStorage['ls2'] = this.href.slice(7).split(".")[0];  

... some other stuff

}
```

Comment: Can't find `.hover_over` anywhere in your HTML... ?

Comment: Will update in a moment. It's a mouseenter. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the html you gave us to work with in your post here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jasenhk/zwdFc/.

Essentially...

```
$(".targetclass").mouseenter(function(e) {
    var data = $(this).data("name");
    console.log(data);
});
```

Some things to note:

1. Your html does not specify a element with the `hover_over` class. This makes it hard for others to replicate your problem.
2. In your `mouseenter` handler, `this` might not be what you think it is -- check its value.

**Edit** Thanks for the fiddle. You need to search using `.find` to traverse to your target element.

```
$(".hoverclass").mouseenter(function(e) {
    var data = $(this).find(".targetclass").data("log-name");
    console.log(data);

    $("#result").html("the result is:" + data);
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the extra work—thanks. Your fiddle is finding values I don't need. I'm trying to get "What_I_Need" which is the attr value. I'm using "this" in the example to get the value of an href which I then parse and store locally. That works fine. Back to the original issue: I need to get the attr value and the HTML is representative except for the top level div that I used in the description.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question or post a fiddle to clear up some confusion.

Comment: Thanks! Works in the fiddle now but didn't in the live code at first attempt. Will take a break and try again later. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially...

```
$(".hover_over").mouseenter( function(){
    // If target is a direct descendent:
    var $data_name = $(this).children(".targetclass").data("name");

    // If target is within other child(ren):
    var $data_name = $(this).find(".targetclass").data("name");

    // do something else with $data_name
    console.log( $data_name );
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that returns a null. I'm trying to get the attribute "data-name" value. I don't understand why it appears you changed that to "name" although putting "data-name" there didn't work either.

Comment: He is using the data function which should return the attribute matching `data-` plus the string parameter. If it returns null, it might mean that either your binding selector is wrong, or you are adding the data-name attribute improperly?

Comment: @jlange  Thanks but still not clear on this. "$data_name" could be anything? Say "foo" since it's just a name for the var, right? The live code's attribute is "data-log-name" although I shortened it in the example so I replaced his `.data("name")` with `.data("log-name")` but still no joy. It returns null.

Comment: @user1452893 sounds like you're using a bad selector. What value do you get with `console.log($(".hover_over").length)`?

Comment: @Jasen I get 11. If the selector was bad wouldn't the working `localStorage['ls2'] = this.href.slice(7).split(".")[0];` fail? Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
$(".targetclass").hover(function(){
    var data = $(this).attr("data-name");
 }, function(){});
```

Comment: I can't hover over .targetclass. .hover_over is the top-level div .

Comment: `hover` is simply shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseout` in jQuery.